# How to set up a cron job to start and stop a java jar?

Tags: java, cron

I have compiled my JAVA code into a jar file which I have ported to my ubuntu server.  I can start it manually the usual way using `java -jar myJar.jar` but I'd like my program to be active only for 8 hours.  How can I go about setting my jar file up as a process which starts at 9AM and also which automatically closes at 5PM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write a simple launcher script that does the following:

- Takes two command line options:

  - `--start`

    - Set up the classpath and environment like JAVA_HOME for the jar to run.
    - Spawn `java -jar myJar.jar`.
    - Capture the process ID and store it in the `myJar.pid` file in a specific location.
  - `--stop`

    - Read the process ID from `myJar.pid` and send a `kill` signal.

Then schedule two jobs in [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto), one to call this launcher script with `--start` argument, at 9AM, and the other to call the same script with `--stop` argument, at 5PM.

I would also have a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) registered in my application to gracefully exit when the kill signal is issued.

Comment: +1 - great answer. I also like the mention of including a shutdown hook.

Comment: Thank you, this put me on the right path.  Also, I love the shutdown hook.  I've been programming JAVA for a while now but I've never come across this.  It will be useful for many occasions!  Thanks again!